# Не создается событие в календаре

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-calendar

```
function onFormSubmit(e){
  var calId="calendarId"
  var recdate=new Date(e.namedValues["Датазаписи"][0])
  MailApp.sendEmail("xxxx@gmail.com", "Новая запись в таблице",e.namedValues["ФИО"][0]+"\n"+recdate)
  CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createAllDayEvent(e.namedValues["ФИО"][0],recdate)
  CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId).createAllDayEvent(e.namedValues["ФИО"][0],recdate)
}
```

Дата получается в виде `Mon Jan 03 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Восточная Америка, стандартное время)`.
Письмо приходит. Оба способа создания события не работают. ЧЯДНТ?

Comment: А что в логе пишется?

Comment: @PrianichkinSergey а как смотерть лог? я же через форму отправляю

Comment: А код этот где находится?

Comment: Откуда ж вы знаете, что дата приходит в таком формате? Откуда этот код? В каком триггере он отрабатывает? `onFormSubmit` не может быть простым.